# How to get facebook code from redirect uri in Java desktop application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

im a newbie in graph facebook api. I try to get MY_VERIFICATION_CODE by send http request:

**link1:** https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

and then Facebook will redirect to http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html? code=MY_VERIFICATION_CODE

but I cant get code from response. I copy **link1** to chrome,  it redirects to url with a code appended as parameter, but this url stays just for seconds and then it changes to this: [https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_)

My question is how to read the code from the redirected uri in a java desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

It's all described in the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#login

Quote:

> When using a desktop app and logging in, Facebook redirects people to the redirect_uri mentioned above and places an access token along with some other metadata (such as token expiry time) in the URI fragment:
>
> `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...`
>
> Your app needs to detect this redirect and then read the access token out of the URI using the mechanisms provided by the OS and development framework you are using. You can then skip straight to the Inspecting access tokens step.

Comment: yes it mentioned but how can I get to know that the app has been redirected to that URL.?

Comment: Exactly. I agree with sonu